# Beginner Steps to Configure a Java Project to Build with Apache Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, build

I've been given the task of migrating an existing project -- formerly built with Ant -- to use Apache Maven. I'm brand new to the entire concept, though I've spent the last several hours doing as much research as I can on the subject. Sadly, I'm having some proxy issues when it comes to installing things like m2e and Eclipse IAM, so everything must be done from the command prompt. As of right now, I do have maven installed properly; the trick now is to use it in my project rather than Ant. I've looked online and found a few tutorials, but they are all too vague for me considering my lack of experience with all of this. If anyone can break the steps down for me one-by-one in a detailed manner, that would be more than amazing. On a side note, I've been told to add the following to the local Maven Settings:

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
        <id>local_tomcat</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>tomcat</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>artifactory</id>
      <name>Artifactory</name>
      <url>https://jenkins.web.jw.local/artifactory/repo1</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.jw.local</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.jw.local</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

With the obvious username and password information filled in. I think I've managed that thus far by simply adding the necessary blocks into the settings.xml file under my ApacheMaven\conf directory. Other than that single step, I'm pretty much lost. Again, any help, especially that of a detailed tutorial in terms of command line instructions to build this project would be wonderful. Oh, and on another side-note, I am using Eclipse... Not sure if that would matter much.

**EDIT**: Considering Petr Kozelka's answer, I've attempted to make a pom.xml file for my project. Here's what I have so far...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>appName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Application Name</name>
    <description>Yadda Yadda</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Is this heading in the right direction? Also, do I need to construct the archetype.xml file myself, or will Maven do that through the command line somehow? If I need to do it myself, this is what I've come up with thus far:

```
<archetype xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-1.0.0.xsd">
    <id>lighthouse</id>
    <sources>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/controller/AddTimeController.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/controller/BugController.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/controller/DeleteTimeController.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/controller/EnterTimeController.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/controller/ModifyTimeController.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/controller/PersonController.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/controller/ProjectController.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/controller/TimeController.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/model/Area.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/model/Bug.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/model/DBModel.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/model/DefaultModel.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/model/JWModel.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/model/JWTime.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/model/Person.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/model/Project.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/util/Lighthouse.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/util/LighthouseApplicationListener.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/util/LighthouseServlet.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/util/LighthouseSystemProperties.java</source>
        <source>src/com/jeldwen/lighthouse/LighthouseApp.java</source>
    </sources>
    <testSources>
        <!-- None -->
    </testSources>
    <allowPartial>true</allowPartial>
</archetype>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Figuring out how to build with maven?

Comment: the pom is ok; but I doubt you need to do anything with archetypes, as they are designed for preparing "templates" of maven application. Maybe you will _use_ archetypes at the beginning, but I doubt that your Maven experience needs to start with _designing_ them

Comment: @Ryan: I've never used maven before, and with the m2e plugin not working yet, I'm trying to build -- or convert from Ant -- my existing project with Maven. I'm just so new to the concept that I'm having trouble figuring out where to begin and pinpointing the precise steps needed to do this; the tutorials I've seen in the past aren't quite as helpful for a newbie like me, is all...

Comment: @Petr: Alright, so once this pom.xml file is done, I just run maven (or whatever the right term is) with "mvn clean install" once I've selected the proper directory, right?

Comment: exactly - you need to stay in the directory containing `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: if you wish to customize settings.xml, do not touch the one in maven distro - instead, create a new file in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` where maven finds and uses it.

**As the very first step**, I recommend you to not use settings.xml at all.
Create a supersimple maven project, and try to compile it:

```
mvn clean install
```

**Second step**

Use very simple settings.xml:

- you probably do not need proxy
- servers part is needed only for publishing artifacts to a maven repository; that's not important at the beginning
- here it is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>repos</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>internal mirror</name>
      <url>https://jenkins.web.jw.local/artifactory/repo1</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <!-- TODO: the proxy part here -->
</settings>
```

This assumes that you use inhouse maven repository, for instance [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.com) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/).

Using maven repo makes only sense if your projects are not happy with deps available in the [Maven Central Repository](https://repository.sonatype.org) - otherwise, you can safely go without it. *(let's neglect the performance effect of repoman for now)*

**Now,** add some java sources, dependencies etc. - and watch how new depenencies get automatically downloaded to your local repository...

**Third step**

Learn how to add further repositories to your repository manager (group "public" on Nexus)...

The rest is probably subject of further research.

Comment: Thank you. I tried running the 'mvn clean install' in the command line, but I still need to create a pom file for my project. Any pointers on how that might work? Also, my company does have some proxy settings, so I think I do need to include what was given to me in that regard. In addition, I was told to use the repository found at 'https://jenkins.web.jw.local/artifactory/repo1'. I'm not sure if that makes a difference, or how I'd add that correctly...

Comment: sure, if you are behind a proxy, then it's unavoidable; + use exactly the url that you were told, it really **does** matter (I originally assumed it was just a sample url)

Comment: Ah. Yeah, I'm behind a proxy, which probably explains the need for this separate repository.

Comment: not exactly - if the repository resides at the same side of the proxy as you, then you need only the `mirrors` part (proxy is configured on the repo); if it's on opposite side, you need also the `proxy` part in order to reach the repository

Comment: Alright, I think I understand this a bit more. I spoke with my supervisor again, and there are apparently two repositories I need. One is simply our mirror of the Maven repository which should be specified in the setting.xml file, while the other contains company-specific jar files that need to be accessed through the proxy via the pom.xml... Or something like that. Yeah, I'm brand new to web development entirely, so this whole proxy thing is a rather new obstacle in my world.

Comment: on nexus, the admin typically creates a repository group which aggregates all needed external repository proxies(caches) including central, and also all internal hosted repos with company specific content. Then, your settings only references this group as if it was one single repo. Check if this scenario is available in your company - I don't know artifactory, but I suppose it has similar concepts for grouping, proxing and hosting repositories.

Comment: Yeah, I just double checked. The artifactory is my company's mirror to the central maven repository. I got a better rundown of what's going on with that now. I also apparently forgot to set-up my directory structure to match what maven looks for. So now I just need to update my dependencies so that it will build, and it should be all good. Thanks again.